# Multiple javascript toggle for tree structure

Tags: javascript, html, css, toggle

I have a Tree structure with Unlimited Nodes, How to put `Togglable content` under each node?
I mean `Togglable content` is same for all nodes.
I set `min-width` and `min-height` for `.tree li a` and I want `Togglable content` be under `.tree li a` .
Now toggle work for 1 node and that is'nt under each node.
Photo:
[image: photo]

```js
    var toggle = document.getElementById("toggle");
    var content = document.getElementById("content");

    toggle.addEventListener("click", function () {
      content.classList.toggle("appear");
    }, false);
```

```css
  body {
      font-family: sans-serif;
      font-size: 15px;
    }

    .tree {
      transform: rotate(0deg);
      transform-origin: 50%;
    }

    .tree ul {
      position: relative;
      padding: 1em 0;
      white-space: nowrap;
      margin: 0 auto;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .tree ul::after {
      content: '';
      display: table;
      clear: both;
    }

    .tree li {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: top;
      text-align: center;
      list-style-type: none;
      position: relative;
      padding: 1em 0.5em 0 0.5em;
    }

    .tree li::before,
    .tree li::after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 50%;
      border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
      width: 50%;
      height: 1em;
    }

    .tree li::after {
      right: auto;
      left: 50%;
      border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    }

    .tree li:only-child::after,
    .tree li:only-child::before {
      display: none;
    }

    .tree li:only-child {
      padding-top: 0;
    }

    .tree li:first-child::before,
    .tree li:last-child::after {
      border: 0 none;
    }

    .tree li:last-child::before {
      border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
    }

    .tree li:first-child::after {
      border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    }

    .tree ul ul::before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 50%;
      border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
      width: 0;
      height: 1em;
    }

    .tree li a {
      min-width: 16em;
      min-height: 5em;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      padding: 0.5em 0.75em;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
      border-radius: 5px;
      color: #333;
      position: relative;
      top: 1px;
      transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    .tree li a:hover,
    .tree li a:hover+ul li a {
      background: #e9453f;
      color: #fff;
      border: 1px solid #e9453f;
    }

    .tree li a:hover+ul li::after,
    .tree li a:hover+ul li::before,
    .tree li a:hover+ul::before,
    .tree li a:hover+ul ul::before {
      border-color: #e9453f;
    }

    #content {
      /* DON'T USE DISPLAY NONE/BLOCK! Instead: */
      background: #cf5;
      padding: 10px;
      position: inherit;
      visibility: hidden;
      opacity: 0.4;
      transition: 0.6s;
      -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
      transform: translateY(-20%);
      -webkit-transform: translateY(-20%);
    }

    #content.appear {
      visibility: visible;
      opacity: 1;
      transform: translateX(0);
      -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center tree">
      <ul>
        <li id="toggle">
          <a href="#">parent</a>
          <ul>
            <li id="toggle">
              <a href="#">boy</a>
            </li>
            <li id="toggle">
              <a href="#">girl</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <div id="content">This Togglable content is same for all id="toggle"</div>

    </div>
  </div>

  
</body>
```

Comment: So do you expect the message to only appear when you click the root node?

Comment: No, Togglable content is 3 Buttons (del update add) and I want to put under each tree node and user clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

✔️ Solved With This way:

```js
  function toggleDocs(event) {
var next = event.target.nextElementSibling;
if (next.style.display == "none") {
  next.style.display = "block";

} else {
  next.style.display = "none";
}
  }
  document.addEventListener('click', toggleDocs, true);
```

```css
  body {
      font-family: sans-serif;
      font-size: 15px;
    }

    .tree {
      transform: rotate(0deg);
      transform-origin: 50%;
    }

    .tree ul {
      position: relative;
      padding: 1em 0;
      white-space: nowrap;
      margin: 0 auto;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .tree ul::after {
      content: '';
      display: table;
      clear: both;
    }

    .tree li {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: top;
      text-align: center;
      list-style-type: none;
      position: relative;
      padding: 1em 0.5em 0 0.5em;
    }

    .tree li::before,
    .tree li::after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 50%;
      border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
      width: 50%;
      height: 1em;
    }

    .tree li::after {
      right: auto;
      left: 50%;
      border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    }

    .tree li:only-child::after,
    .tree li:only-child::before {
      display: none;
    }

    .tree li:only-child {
      padding-top: 0;
    }

    .tree li:first-child::before,
    .tree li:last-child::after {
      border: 0 none;
    }

    .tree li:last-child::before {
      border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
    }

    .tree li:first-child::after {
      border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    }

    .tree ul ul::before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 50%;
      border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
      width: 0;
      height: 1em;
    }

    .tree li a {
      min-width: 16em;
      min-height: 5em;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      padding: 0.5em 0.75em;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
      border-radius: 5px;
      color: #333;
      position: relative;
      top: 1px;
      transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    .tree li a:hover,
    .tree li a:hover+ul li a {
      background: #e9453f;
      color: #fff;
      border: 1px solid #e9453f;
    }

    .tree li a:hover+ul li::after,
    .tree li a:hover+ul li::before,
    .tree li a:hover+ul::before,
    .tree li a:hover+ul ul::before {
      border-color: #e9453f;
    }

    #content {
      /* DON'T USE DISPLAY NONE/BLOCK! Instead: */
      background: #cf5;
      padding: 10px;
      position: inherit;
      visibility: hidden;
      opacity: 0.4;
      transition: 0.6s;
      -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
      transform: translateY(-20%);
      -webkit-transform: translateY(-20%);
    }

    #content.appear {
      visibility: visible;
      opacity: 1;
      transform: translateX(0);
      -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12 text-center tree">
  <ul>
    <li class="clickable-heading">
      <a href="#">parent</a>
      <div style="display:none">This is Togglable 1</div>
      <ul>
        <li class="clickable-heading">
          <a href="#">boy</a>
          <div style="display:none">This is Togglable 2</div>
        </li>
        <li class="clickable-heading">
          <a href="#">girl</a>
          <div style="display:none">This is Togglable 3</div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
  </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not use the same `id` for multiple elements, `id` should always be unique.

Use `class` instead.

```
<li class="toggle"> ... </li>
```

Then you can create an array of objects in JavaScript to access these elements:

```
let toggle_list = document.querySelectorAll(".toggle");
```

Then you can use a `for` loop (or, `forEach` method, if you want to be fancy) to assign an event listener to each of them:

```
for(let i = 0; i < toggle_list.length; i++) {
  toggle_list[i].addEventListener("click", toggleClick);
}
```

Now you can define your toggleClick function something like this:

```
function toggleClick(e) {
  e.target.children[0].classList.toggle("appear");
}
```

In this example, `children[0]` will target the first element inside the `<li>` that is clicked, and that child element does not need a separate `class="content"` attribute. You can change it to something else, if that's not what you want (perhaps `children[1]` :D ).

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Comment: Should I have 1 content in `yourFunction`? I mean   let toggle_list = document.querySelectorAll(".toggle");
    content = document.getElementById("content");
    for (let i = 0; i < toggle_list.length; i++) {
      toggle_list[i].addEventListener("click", content.classList.toggle("appear"));

    };

Comment: Don't use getElementById() if you want to get multiple elements. No two elements on the page should have the same id.

Comment: I want to show 1 `Togglable content` Div for all classes, I'm confused, is better to using 1 `Togglable content` or no? 3 button under each node (add del update)

Comment: Edited the answer to make it more clear. You don't need content class at all.

Comment: in my code `toggle.addEventListener` was false by default, I mean       visibility

Comment: What do you want to happen when the user clicks on the <li> element? If you want a child of that element to appear, I've given you the answer.

Comment: I want `Togglable content`  be hide, and after user click on each node , show under each node, I tested your code and `Togglable content ` is visible and not work, can you put your code in Expand snippet please.

Comment: <div id="content">This Togglable content is same for all id="toggle"</div>

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Did you checked my  Expand snippet code? I have a green toggable content under last node, I want when user clicked on  `<li class="toggle">` toggle down This ``` <div class="content">This Togglable content is same for all id="toggle"</div>``` , if user clicked on parent, show that under parent, if user clicked on boy, show that under boy and .... this is a small menu for each node

Comment: You have to have that div inside every <li>.  And you can't use the same id on multiple items.

Comment: Can I add after li? because my css get problem, I updated my question with a photo, I want this. a smooth slide down menu for each node

Answer (score -1):

As far as i know `id` attribute should be unique for html document

You can try do use `data-` attribute and then match an element for example by `data-toggle`

[link for documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)